# Acceptable notation? $\lesssim_{n} n^{-\beta}$ for constants NOT depending on $n$

Tags: notation, proof-writing, article-writing, publishing

I am preparing a paper and found it convenient to write things like
$$
|\text{Expression of a lot of variables}|\lesssim_{n} n^{-\beta}
$$
when an inequality is true up to a multiplicative factor that does NOT depend on $n$. Unfortunately, so far I have ever only seen people use this notation in the opposite meaning that would interpret $n$ as the only thing that the constant depends on.

The reason I want to use the notation differently, is that otherwise I would have to use a lot more subscripts.

I do currently clearly state what I mean by my notation. Also the inequalities are almost always as easy as above such that no one could misinterpret them without intention (the above would mean $|\text{Expression}|=0$ for all $n>1$ if the constant did not depend on $\beta$).

I still wanted to ask if you think changing canonical notation like this is a good idea or would annoy people. Or maybe you haven't seen either notation and there is not even a canon I could break.

Comment: If you explain what you mean by the notation then there's certainly no problem. (If you don't explain: Why not?)

Comment: Including the *irrelevant* variables as subscripts seems strange to me. On a first read I doubt I'd catch the explanation of the notation and might get frustrated with it before actually finding that explanation.

Comment: This is exactly what is meant by $$f(n)=O\left(n^{-\beta}\right).$$

Comment: @Did the problem is that my left hand sides are not actually $f(n)$ but things like $\|q(u_n,y)\|_{L^2(\Omega,H^{\beta}(U)}$ and sometimes it is important that the constant also does not depend on, say, $y$. In this example, excluding dependence on $y$ and $n$ would still be easier than including dependence on $\beta$, $U$, $\Omega$ and $q$. I edited my question accordingly